# Is it correct to use the word "wrongdoing" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Is 'wrongdoing' used appropriately in this sentence?

**The wrongdoing of spying on students is not only in the boundaries of law, but it is also morally inappropriate.**

Comment: What is the question? Why do you think it might be inappropriate?

Comment: It might depend on exactly what you want your statement to *mean*, but I think most likely the word you should be questioning here is "limited", not "wrongdoing". Most likely the boundaries of law didn't actual "limit" the offence - if it *had*, the crime would probably have been prevented, and thus not "exist" at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for your comment. The mobile app had posted the question incorrectly. I've edited the question. Could you please take a look at it again? Thx

Comment: @bib: I've edited the question! Can you please take a look at it again? Thx

Comment: Simple *Is this right?* questions are not usually answered on this site. In general, we try to answer *why*. Hve you looked at dictionary definitions of *wrongdoing*? What is there about the definition that makes you think it might or might not be okay?

Comment: @bib: Yes I have. My question is regarding its specific use in this sentence. Maybe it would have been better if I had asked _does this statement make sense?_

Comment: @Miro: The sentence is hopelessly flawed, but I don't have time to give a full explanation now of exactly *why*. I suggest you discard *not only* and *but*, and end the first sentence after *law*. Then consider carefully how that "new" first sentence could be written out more clearly. Bear in mind that as it stands, I as a native speaker would naturally expect ***outside*** or ***beyond** the boundaries of law*. I think I understand exactly what you are trying to say - but it's fairly complex, so you need to use more words *there*, and not try to conjoin it with the second sentence.

Comment: Or just take the easy way out and say *Spying on students is not only illegal, it is also immoral*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yeah, I was thinking about the same thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Along the same vein @FumbleFingers suggested:  "[The] spying on students represents not only a legal transgression, but a moral one as well."

Comment: @David: Thanks for the sentence.. The word 'transgression' seems to be the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Wrongdoing' means *actions* that are wrong. So it would be appropriate to say "the man was caught in numerous wrongdoings, including spying on students". If i substitute that into your sentence i get "the wrong action of spying on students is not only in the boundary of the law..." which doesn't read well and probably isn't what you meant.

However what I think you mean is "wrongness", i.e. the property of being wrong. To put your sentence rather simpler, "spying on students is wrong, not only because it is outside the boundaries of the law but also because it is morally inappropriate".

Comment: Thank.. I was exactly looking for this. I thought of using wrongness but couldn't fit it into the sentence. Your proposed sentence is very simple and flows well.. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have glossed over the fact that OP's original text was apparently intended to convey something along the lines of *the classification of "wrongness" [for this activity] applies/arises **within the context of** [the boundaries of] law* (not *it's **beyond/crosses** legal limits/boundaries*). Which I think is a fairly subtle argument which can validly be made, but would normally only be used in contexts where one wished to contrast that *technically "wrong"* sense with another perspective from which the activity would *not* be viewed as "bad".